# When we `import { foo }`, why can't we `export foo` but have to `export { foo }`?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6

I wonder why after we

```
import { foo } from "some/path";
```

we don't

```
export foo;
```

as usual, but have to

```
export { foo };
```

in order to be able to export it?

The reason is that we usually export a "named" export by

```
export const bar = 123;

const wah = 234;
export wah;
```

and they export without a `{ }`.

Comment: is the import and export foo happening in the same file?

Comment: Are you sure that it works? According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export), `export wah;` is not valid.

Answer (score 4):

No. `export foo;` or `export wah;` are not *usual*. They just don't work.

You usually create a named export using either

```
export const wah = 234;
```

or

```
const wah = 234;
export { wah }
```

or

```
const bar = 234;
export { bar as wah }
```

---

Btw, you can also directly do

```
export { foo } from "some/path";
```

Comment: Also isn't `export { foo }` just a shorthand for `export {foo: foo}`

Comment: @Bulkan No, it's a shorthand for `export { foo as foo }` (see my `bar` example)